# preg_match_all() Uses

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I have a variable $html

in which this code is stored

```
<form action="track_mobile.asp" method="post" name="TrackMobile">
<table width="99%" height="55" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="Heading2" colspan="2">&nbsp;Track Any Mobile Location</td>
                  </tr>

<tr>
<td width="21" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="s2stextbox" valign="top"><img src="../images/operators_logo/Tata.png" width="134" height="121" align="left"> </td>
<td width="897" valign="top" class="s2stextbox"><font size="2"><b>Mobile Number:     </b>918888888888</font></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
           <td width="897" valign="top" class="s2stextbox" valign="top"><font size="2">      <b>User Name:</b> We are unable to trace the Name for this Mobile Number<br>
<font size="2"><b>Mobile Operator Name:</b> TATA TELESERVICES<br>
<b>State/Region: </b>Maharashtra</font></td>
</tr>   </table>
</form>
```

In which every item after ":(semicollon)" are random which comes different every time.

Plz give me correct syntax to get echo as

```
Mobile Number: 918888888888
User Name: We are unable to trace the Name for this Mobile Number
Mobile Operator Name: IDEA
State/Region: Maharashtra
```

in which
these are ramdomly generated, different evey time so, that preg_match search this loaction and echo the text which are there in same loaction

```
918888888888
We are unable to trace the Name for this Mobile Number
IDEA
Maharashtra
```

Comment: Add a `regex` tag to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Strip-out HTML tag

```
$text = strip_tags($html);
```

### 2. Match using text before column

I just change the regexp and display each value match by `(.*)` (everything that follow the pattern up to the end of line:

```
preg_match('/Mobile Number: (.*)/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
preg_match('/User Name: (.*)/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
preg_match('/Mobile Operator Name: (.*)/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
preg_match('/State/Region: (.*)/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: But the output is comming like this "We are unable to trace the Name for this Mobile NumberMobile Operator Name: IDEAState/Region: Maharashtra" with many non gaps i want it like by line sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work for `XPath` (see [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`][1], your XPaths look like be:

### 918888888888

```
/form/table/tr[1]/td[2]/font[substring-after(./text(), ':') ->
```

### We are unable to trace the Name for this Mobile Number

```
/form/table/tr[2]/td[1]/font[1][substring-after(./text(), ':')
```

### TATA TELESERVICES

```
/form/table/tr[2]/td[1]/font[2][substring-before(substring-after(./text(), ':'), 'State')
```

### Maharashtra

```
/form/table/tr[2]/td[1]/font[2][substring-after(./text(), 'Region')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am using this with curl.So, Plz can you give me full code which i can put in my php page and got this output as i am new in PHP. Thanks in advance

Comment: How to get Echo via preg_match Tag.
And Plz give me full code as i am new in PHP.
so that i can copy and paste this code in my PHP file to got echo which i really need by searching in HTML.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also provide preg_match to echo all content between <form> </form>. I Just want to search this code in my 5000+ line HTML code. and want to echo back only the selected content which is between <form> Tag.

Comment: this is the occasion to learn a powerful for HTML/XML manipulation